# How can I edit/update in a textfield that is disabled ? Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<input data-test-id="input-name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" class="tw-w-full tw-bg-transparent tw-px-2 tw-mr-2 " value="john chrome" disabled="" xpath="1">

<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

this is my script:

```
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/*[1]").click()
edit_name.send_keys("John")
```

Im trying to click the button first so that the textfield will enable and i used send_keys but it wont work

Comment: do you have the website link ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Javescript executor will solve your problem

```
name_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/*[1]")

# remove disable attribute from html tag
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("disabled");', name_ele)
```

Comment: It works thank you, should i use send key function to enter a value in the textfield ?

Comment: Yeah, use send key function usually work for me. Try it your self

Comment: Great. Glad to help you mate :))

Comment: another question because there are like 5 text field that disabled should i do the same ? so basically my test case is ill fill up all the text field and i will save it.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Try to locate the element first then execute javascript command as my answer. It should work

Comment: this is my second script 
occupation_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body/div[@id='root']/div[2]/div[2]/form[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("dsiabled");', occupation_ele)
print(name_ele.is_enabled())
# occupation_ele.clear()
occupation_ele.send_keys("Work")

Comment: but im getting an error 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johnnatividad/PycharmProjects/Newbailiwikauto/bailiwik session/crossbrowsing.py", line 61, in <module>
    occupation_ele.send_keys("Work")
  File "/Users/johnnatividad/PycharmProjects/Newbailiwikauto/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,

Comment: Can you post it in comment section. It hard to read here. Post the html and the error you receive

Comment: i post a new comment :)